# How auto increment id and insert 2 rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-insert

I have two table with one to one relation and I want to insert two rows to the tables with the same auto increment id. Is it possible?

```
create table first
(
    id    bigint primary key,
    value varchar(100) not null
);

create table second
(
    id   bigint references first (id),
    sign boolean
);


insert into first(id, value)
values (-- autoincremented, 'some_value');

insert into second(id, sign)
values (-- the same autoincremented, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `id` column must be defined as an "auto increment" one before you can use that:

```
create table first
(
    id    bigint generated always as identity primary key,
    value varchar(100) not null
);
```

Then you can use `lastval()` to get the last generated id:

```
insert into first(id, value)
values (default, 'some_value');

insert into second(id, sign)
values (lastval(), true);
```

Or if you want to be explicit:

```
insert into first(id, value)
values (default, 'some_value');

insert into second(id, sign)
values (currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('first','id')), true);
```

Comment: @a_ Grand thanks. Could you write please how to insert several rows? May be it possible?

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a cte with the `returning` clause:

```
with i as (
    insert into first(value) values('some_value')
    returning id
)
insert into second(id, sign) 
select i.id, true from i
```

This performs the two inserts at once; the `id` of the first insert is auto-generated, and then used in the second insert.

For this to work, you need the `id` of the `first` table to be defined as  `serial`.

Comment: Thank u for response. Is it normal to use with to insert several pairs ?

Comment: @Vlad: yes that's ok in Postgres (you can see that [in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html))